# Strange reply when uploading zip file to amazon S3 using REST ,QT and PUT request

Tags: qt, rest, amazon-s3

iam trying to upload zip file to S3 amazon but i have problem.
i am using QT : sending request and receiving reply.
i am sending the URL with zip file here is the code :

```
    QFile *file = new QFile(fileName);
    QString fileSize = QString::number(file->size());

    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QByteArray data(file->readAll());

    QNetworkRequest req;
    QNetworkReply* rep;

    req.setUrl(QUrl(url /*cant post the real URL*/));
    req.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Length").toUtf8(), fileSize.toUtf8());

    rep = m_manager->post(req, data);

    connect(rep, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();

    CheckReply(rep);
```

and here is CheckReply function

```
bool CheckReply(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
  if (reply->error())
  {
    qDebug() << "ERROR!";
    qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
     qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader).toString();
     qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::LastModifiedHeader).toDateTime().toString();
     qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toULongLong();
     qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
     qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();
     return true;
  }
}
```

the problem is , CheckReply() shows this msg : "Error downloading -request URL-".
why this happens , it is upload NOT download.

thanks

Comment: technically, s3 is downloading what you're uploading...

Comment: can you please check if my code wrong because i cant find the problem.
i mean always get "Error downloading -request URL-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i find the problem , in case any one face the same problem.

the bug was that i use `QUrl(QSting)` , to set the request url.

instead of that use this : `QUrl::fromEncoded(QByteArray)` or

`QUrl::fromEncoded(/your QString/.toUtf8())`.

Comment: here is where i found the answer , http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52604-Replacing-QHttp-get()-with-QNetworkAccessManager?s=3aa086612225aa1e7a30b6c4e199239a